# Adding Custom VIew- Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-custom-view

I have following layout file. It has camera preview on half screen and button with it. I want to add a custom View which draws circle. I have done coding the class Custom View class. But now the problem is **how/what to do in order to add my Custom view in layout and how to integrate that to my main class**. I have not been able to get it properly working so far.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:baselineAligned="false">


<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/camera_preview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <MyDrawing
        android:id="@+id/Drawing"
        android:layout_width="259dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        />

</LinearLayout>


<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/buttonsLayout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="1">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_capture"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
        android:text="Capture/Stop"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: where you want to add it and what custom view you are trying to add

Comment: want to show add that custom view( which draws circle) over the Camera Preview.

Comment: you want to show that at a specific location?? how you are getting the location(pixel)

Comment: I am just drawing a circle(50f radii), its radius is constant. Just want to show it in center or at corner point of camerapreview. Will dynamically move it later over the preview. But so far just showing it over preview is problem,.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this :

```
<MyDrawing
        android:id="@+id/Drawing"
        android:layout_width="259dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        />
```

To:

```
<com.package.file.location.MyDrawing
        android:id="@+id/Drawing"
        android:layout_width="259dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        />
```

**Always add complete path to the view**

Comment: Okay. Gowtham can you let me know how to integrate it in my Main class onCreate method too.

Comment: last time when i tried to declare that in my main class, it gave Layout inflator exception. Was the "com.package.file.location.MyDrawing" line creating this exception ?

Comment: you should replace "com.package.file.location" with your package name

Comment: Here is a nice tutorial you could use to get started http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android-sdk-creating-custom-views--mobile-14548

Comment: Gowtham, let me try that, if it works its double Thumbs UP. will get back to you over it . Thanks for now